# NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

when I execute my angular application locally, this error occurred suddenly even without doing any code changes while the same code base can be run in a separate machine with the same configuration.

- node version:v16.17.0

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following import in AppModule file

```
imports: [ 
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    ...
  ],
```

To import RouterModule you should do something like this:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Comment: those configurations are already there in the code.